# Limits Under the Integral Sign

Tags: integration, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $$F_n:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$$ be a sequence of positive measurable functions s.t. $F_n \to F$ pointwise and
$$\int_{\mathbb R} F_n\ d\lambda \to \int_{\mathbb R} F\ d\lambda <\infty$$
let $f_n$ be an other sequence s.t. $\forall n\ |f_n|<F_n$ and $\exists f:\ f_n \to f$ pointwise.
I have to prove that
$$\int_{\mathbb R} f_n\ d\lambda \to \int_{\mathbb R} f\ d\lambda <\infty$$
$$$$
I tried in this way, that should work for $f_n$ positive:
By Fatou's lemma
$$\liminf_n \int_{\mathbb R} f_n\ d\lambda \ge \int_{\mathbb R} \liminf f_n\ d\lambda=\int_{\mathbb R} f\ d\lambda$$
again by the same result,
$$\liminf_n \int_{\mathbb R} F_n-f_n\ d\lambda \ge \int_{\mathbb R} \liminf F_n-f_n\ d\lambda=\int_{\mathbb R} F-f\ d\lambda$$
So, by assumtion
$$\int_{\mathbb R} F-\liminf_ n \int_{\mathbb R} f_n\ d\lambda \ge \int_{\mathbb R} F-\int_{\mathbb R}f\ d\lambda$$
which means
$$\liminf_ n \int_{\mathbb R} f_n\ d\lambda \le \int_{\mathbb R}f\ d\lambda$$
that proves
$$\liminf_ n \int_{\mathbb R} f_n\ d\lambda = \int_{\mathbb R}f\ d\lambda$$
Is there a way to remove the hypothesis of $f_n>0$ and change $\liminf$ to $\lim$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the old version:

Without the assumption that $f_n$ are positive this is false. Take $F_n=F=0$ and $f_n=-nI_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$, $f=0$.

For the revised version of the question apply Fatou's Lemma to $(F_n+f_n)$ and $(F_n-f_n)$ both of which are positive sequences. This gives (after cancelling $\int F$) $lim \sup \int f_n \leq \int f$ and  $\lim \inf \int f_n \geq \int f$.

Comment: I forgot one modulus

Comment: @DavideMaran I  have edited my answer.